# PictureBox находится над другим PictureBox

Tags: c#

пишу программку, мне нужно, чтобы когда PictureBox1, именуемый "Player", наезжает на определенные картинки PictureBox2-15, именуемые как eat1-14, они пропадали. 
Вот, как это попробовал я:

```
if ((Player.Location.X < eat1.Location.X))
        {
            if ((Player.Location.Y < eat1.Location.Y))
            {
                eat1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Работает очень странно, т.е. иногда еда не съедается, либо съедается только один из 14.

Comment: WinForms, WPF или ещё что?

Comment: [BringToFront()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя есть 2 обьекта описанных Rectangle (прямоугольником).
Это значит что тебе нужно сделать простенькую проверку

Метод будет приблизительно таким:

```
bool RectContains(Rectangle R1, Rectangle R2)
{
    if (   (R2.x+R2.width) < (R1.x+R1.width)
        && (R2.x) > (R1.x)
        && (R2.y) > (R1.y)
        && (R2.y+R2.height) < (R1.y+R1.height)
        )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(код не проверял)

Ну и любую картинку можно описать как Rectangle. То есть точка левого верхнего угла + ширина и высота прямоугольника.

Ну а дальше делай проверку каждые 50 мс(например), если

```
if( RectContains(R1, R2) )
{
     PictureBox2.Destroy(); //ну или визибл = фалс
}
```

Comment: Есть метод [Rectangle.IntersectsWith](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Чудесно! тем более :)